# How to drop an external event on FullCalendar events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm on FullCalendar v5.1.0 with Scheduler.

I use `FullCalendar.Draggable` to create events with a drag and drop from DOM elements outside of FullCalendar.

Now I want to be able to drop my element on the calendar to create an event or on another event to combine them.
I can't find a way to add drop capability on events.

I can use native drag / drop events but they are not triggered anymore when `FullCalendar.Draggable` is activated.

Is there a way to overload `FullCalendar.Draggable` behavior if mouse is over an event ?

Comment: No. The implementation only includes dropping into an empty area of the calendar. The idea is to create new events. If you want to somehow merge it with another event you'd either have to implement that yourself with some custom code, or make a feature request to the fullCalendar maintainers